# Bibliography is not printed using Kile on Ubuntu

Tags: bibliographies

I am having a problem with my LaTeX output that is not printing the bibliography part. I am using Kile to code it. The strange thing is that, it was working out of the box before I reinstalled Ubuntu. After Ubuntu reinstallation, it does not work at all.

A minimal example added by Marco

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
publisher={...},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\cite{test}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

Everybody should consider I have another file of `biblioFile.bib` in the same directory as my LaTeX source file.

Comment: You have to run `bibtex`. You can find it under _View=>Compile=>bibtex_ or use the shortcut ALT+-.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, you need to supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that someone would be able to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, it would be virtually impossible to follow your technical footsteps and solve the problem.

Comment: I've run already using the quickbuild. My quickbuid setting is as follows: PdfLaTeX, PdfLaTeX, BibTeX, BibTeX, PdfLaTeX, PdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Shah: I edited your post. Now you have a minimal example. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Marco: It still doesn't work after trying the minimal example..it returns a single "?".

Comment: @Shah: Please compile the example via the terminal. Maybe Kile have a problem with the path.

Comment: @Marco: I still got the error. ".. LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
"

Comment: @Shah: And what is the output of the compilation via terminal of `bibtex file.aux`

Comment: @Marco: The output of .aux file is "\relax 
\citation{test}
\bibdata{rr6.bib}
\bibstyle{IEEEtran}"

Comment: The package on Fedora Linux is called tetex-IEEEtran.

Comment: I have same problem and suspect that the path to look for the style file is not properly set. Can anyone help on that? thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After running bibtex command, I encountered an error message as follows:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: rr6.aux I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst ---line 4 of file rr6.aux : \bibstyle{IEEEtran : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file rr6.aux
```

This gave a clue to me, I was thinking there might be some missing packages..and after trying to search for "IEEEtran" keyword in the synaptic manager, I found "texlive-publishers" that could be related. After installing it, it turned out that it is again working :-)

Credit should go to Marco for guiding me to fix this. He has provided a very good troubleshooting procedure :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Uninstalled and installed "texlive-publishers" as suggested above, and now the whole thing stopped to work! Most of my packages and fonts were removed and weren't re-installed. I had to spend 2 hours to see what is missing (`texlive-extra` packages, texlive recommended fonts, etc) to reset to the previous installation. Now I am back to something like the previous installation, but the error is still there : "I couln't open style file `IEEEtr.bst`". I changed the style file name to `IEEEtran`, called `IEEEtran`, and removed manually `.aux` file and it worked.

Comment: good to hear that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem in Ubuntu with TexStudio.
I downloaded the file IEEEtranS.bst from (http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtranS.bst), and saved in the current directory with the name IEEEtran.bst, deleted old .aux files.
Compiled and it worked for me